# React: Can't render items in loop

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code, both `Test start` and `Test end` show. Also, the debugger loops correctly through the `areas` and `index`. For some reason, it doesn't render anything that's inside the `{Object.keys(this.state.firstOccurrence.checklist).forEach` statement. What am I missing?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Toast } from 'native-base';

export default class Job extends Component {

  [setting state]      

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        {this.state.firstOccurrence != undefined &&
          <Content padder>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View>
                <Text>Test start</Text>
              </View>
              {Object.keys(this.state.firstOccurrence.checklist).forEach((area, index) => {
                debugger
                return (
                  <View key={index}>
                    <Text>Test {area}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })
              }
              <View>
                <Text>Test end</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Content>
        }
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 65,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
  }
});
```

Comment: how did you set your state...please share complete code to help

Comment: Thanks, I've added more code to show how the state is being set.

Comment: @Geeky I've removed it again to keep the example short and readable, the problem was that I used `forEach` instead of `map` (see below).

Comment: yes i got it ...thanks for the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.forEach` returns undefined. You want `.map`.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I'm new to JS, can you explain why the two behave differently?

Comment: They're just two different functions; why would they behave the same? :-)

Comment: Yeah I guess forEach is thought to manipulate data whereas map is thought to collect data?

Comment: forEach is for imperative things, like mutating objects, dom nodes, or making ajax requests (though, sometimes you use .map for ajax to handle an array of promises).